# Why is copy to specific folder much slower?

Tags: c#, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I have an odd issue copying files from one folder to another on the same drive.

If I copy to a particular folder **PROBLEM_FOLDER** the copying takes a very long time.

If I copy to another folder which I created as a test **OK_FOLDER** the copying is very fast.

I first noticed the problem after I accidentally completely filled my C DRIVE and had to remove a huge number of files from **PROBLEM_FOLDER**.

What could be the issue here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestCopy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           MoveFiles(@"C:\HOTDATA\DB\TEST", @"C:\PROBLEM_FOLDER\DB");
           //MoveFiles(@"C:\HOTDATA\DB\TEST", @"C:\OK_FOLDER\DB");
        }

        public void MoveFiles(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
        {
            foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir,"nEq*-1m*"))
            {

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

                var targetPath = Path.Combine(targetDir, FileName);
                if (File.Exists(targetPath))
                {
                    //File.Delete(targetPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(file, targetPath);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how NTFS (which you more likely have) works, but I guess it has same problem as FAT to work with folder full of files. The more files in the folder = the slower it become. [This](http://serverfault.com/q/98235) proves it.

Comment: Try cleaning your register with CCleaner

Comment: Do you have more files in `Problem_Folder`? if so, this code `File.Exists(targetPath)` will be slower. Do you have indexing on any of the folders?

Comment: @christiandev. I can take File.Exists out. And I still get the same problem

Comment: @Glubus. Why do you think the register may be an issue? For only a specific folder?

Comment: Because you said you deleted a whole bunch of stuff from that folder, to which the register still might hold references.

Answer (score 1):

You might have hidden system files in that folder. Change your view settings to show hidden and untick the hide protected system files. In the old days c# was notoriously slow iterating folders and you have to do things a certain way to work with large folders. This was years ago though, so I don't know if it is still the case.